# SQL Server Database Project option is not included in my Visual Studio 2013 Express Installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have Windows 8 and SQL Server 2012 Express installed. I have also installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Update 5.

Problem : I can't see "SQL Server Database Project" option in "Add New Project" dialog box

I searched the net & it said to install SSDT. So I installed Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013
from https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42313

But when I executed above it asks permission AS SQL Server 2014 [in the permission dialog box Programe Name Appear as SQL Server 2014]

[It installs SQL server 2014 + SSDT for VS 2013 Express for web]

I restarted the PC but still can't see the option.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Deelliiee

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the right things more or less. When you do Help > About in Visual Studio, the SQL Server Data Tools doesn't appear in the list?

Comment: Incidentally why are you using old software?

Comment: It doesn't  list in Help>About Visual Studio. I am following a ContosoUniversity ASP.NET Project Example. For that it Requires to Add SQL Server Database Project.  Can some one help ??

Comment: It may have done a side-by-side installation. You can have more than one version of Visual Studio installed on your computer. Also SSDT has had a confusing history: at times, the BI stuff has been separate.

Comment: If it was my computer, I would uninstall Visual Studio, SQL Server Express, SSMS, and SSDT. Then reinstall using the latest versions: Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014. And why not use Windows 10?

Comment: Hi RichardCL ,   Thank you for the answer. I couldn't fix the problem so I Installed Visual Studio 2015 Express and it works.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. I'm going to have to do a reinstall on my computer now! The 2016 preview SSDT, Integration Services designer, isn't working properly since I installed the latest SSMS 2016. :-S